# How to determine if an element is matched by CSS selector?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given a Selenium WebDriver element instance, I would like to check if that element is matched by a given CSS selector. The functionality is similar jQuery's `is()` function.

I'm using the `.NET` bindings.

Example (suppose the method would be called `Is`)

```
var links = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a"));
foreach (var link in links) 
{
  if (link.Is(".myclass[myattr='myvalue']"))
    // ... do something
  else 
    // ... do some other thing
}
```

Is there any kind of built-in stuff to achieve this, or if not, can anybody suggest a possible implementation? I'm new to Selenium, and have no idea yet.

UPDATE

I see that there is no built-in way to do this. My final goal is to implement methods like jQuery's `parents(selector)` and `closest(selector)`, so any suggestions will be appreciated about this more special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Selenium method that would do the equivalent of jQuery's `$(...).is(...)`. However, the DOM offers [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). It is not a complete replacement for `$(...).is(...)` since it does not support jQuery's extensions to the CSS selector syntax but, then again, Selenium does not support these extensions either.

You'd use it by passing the element you want to test to a JavaScript script that you pass to `ExecuteScript`. This element will appear as the first element of `arguments` inside the script. You just call `matches` on it and return the value. I don't do C# but based on the documentation, I believe it would look like this in C#:

```
bool isIt = (bool)(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(
    "return arguments[0].matches(\".myclass[myattr='myvalue']\")", element);
```

`isIt` contains the result of the test. `element` is the element you want to test, and `driver` is a driver you've already created. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector) for compatibility. In my applications, I use a polyfill to provide `matches` on all platforms I care about.

---

This being said **I do not recommend looping over the elements and testing them one by one**. The problem is that each `ExecuteScript` or `GetAttribute` call is a round-trip between your script and the browser. When you run full test suites, this adds up, especially if the browser is run on a server farm away from your script. Then it **really** ads up. I would structure your test so that it queries a list of all `a` elements and a list of all `a.myclass[myattr='myvalue']` elements. This boils down to two round-trips. From the two lists you have all the information you need to do your `if()` test.

Comment: Thank you. For now the overhead is not relevant, it's a relatively simple, local project, but I will think about your points. Anyway this all is needed because I need to implement something like jQuery's parents and/or closest methods. My plan was to retrieve the parents via XPath, and then check each of them for a given selector match. So in this case probably one round-trip is enough if I implement the parents checking in the passed JavaScript code. What do you think?

Comment: You mean combine `matches` and the other checks in a single `ExecuteScript` call? If yes, then indeed I would recommend doing this. In some circumstances, that's what I do to minimize the number of round-trips.

Comment: Yes I ment that. I could go up the parent line easily and use the matches function to return the closest, or all matching parents. Thank you for the inspiration and the matches function :) didn't know about it, I'm using jQuery for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in order to compare elements in selenium you can compare their `outerHTML` or `innerHTML` representation. It is not bullet-proof, but  should work in practice:

```
IWebElement elm = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".myclass[myattr='myvalue']"));

string linkHtml = link.GetAttribute("outerHTML");
string elmHtml = elm.GetAttribute("outerHTML");

if (linkHtml == elmHtml) {
    ...
}
```

---

Note that in your case, it looks like you can just check the values of `class` and `myattr` attributes using `GetAttribute()`:

```
string linkClass = link.GetAttribute("class");
string linkMyAttr = link.GetAttribute("myattr");

if (linkClass.Contains("myclass") && linkMyAttr == "myvalue") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the first part of your answer, but I don't want to compare two elements. About the second part, yes, in this special example it's enough to check this condition, but I would like a general solution, where I just pass a selector string and Selenium (or the browser) would do the corresponding check.

Comment: Anyway this all is needed because I need to implement something like jQuery's parents and/or closest methods. My plan was to retrieve the parents via XPath, and then check each of them for a given selector match.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási the first part basically says: in order to make a match: find the element by css selector and compare with the element you've got at the moment. Anyway, i really like the Louis's answer here. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was these three methods: `Parent, Parents(selector), Closest(selector)`. After this it could be easy to implement several other jQuery-like helper methods. Hope it's gonna help out someone in the future.

```
    public static IWebElement Parent(this IWebElement elem)
    {
        var script = new[]
        {
            "return",
            "  (function(elem) {",
            "     return elem.parentNode;",
            "   })(arguments[0]);"
        };
        var remoteWebElement = elem as RemoteWebElement;
        if (remoteWebElement == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on RemoteWebElement instances. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        var scriptTxt = script.Implode(separator: " ");
        var scriptExecutor = remoteWebElement.WrappedDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (scriptExecutor == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on drivers implementing IJavaScriptExecutor interface. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        return scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(scriptTxt, elem) as IWebElement;
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Parents(this IWebElement elem, string selector = null)
    {
        var script = new[]
        {
            "return",
            "  (function(elem) {",
            //"     console.log(elem);",
            "     var result = [];",
            "     var p = elem.parentNode;",
            "     while (p && p != document) {",
            //"       console.log(p);",
            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selector) ? null :
                "     if (p.matches && p.matches('" + selector + "'))"),
            "          result.push(p);",
            "       p = p.parentNode;",
            "     }",
            "     return result;",
            "   })(arguments[0]);"
        };
        var remoteWebElement = elem as RemoteWebElement;
        if (remoteWebElement == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on RemoteWebElement instances. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        var scriptTxt = script.Implode(separator: " ");
        var scriptExecutor = remoteWebElement.WrappedDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (scriptExecutor == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on drivers implementing IJavaScriptExecutor interface. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        var resultObj = scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(scriptTxt, elem) as ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>;
        if (resultObj == null)
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(new List<IWebElement>());
        return resultObj;
    }

    public static IWebElement Closest(this IWebElement elem, string selector)
    {
        var script = new[]
        {
            "return",
            "  (function(elem) {",
            "     var p = elem;",
            "     while (p && p != document) {",
            "       if (p.matches && p.matches('" + selector + "'))",
            "          return p;",
            "       p = p.parentNode;",
            "     }",
            "     return null;",
            "   })(arguments[0]);"
        };
        var remoteWebElement = elem as RemoteWebElement;
        if (remoteWebElement == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on RemoteWebElement instances. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        var scriptTxt = script.Implode(separator: " ");
        var scriptExecutor = remoteWebElement.WrappedDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (scriptExecutor == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported on drivers implementing IJavaScriptExecutor interface. Got: {0}".FormatWith(elem.GetType().Name));

        return scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(scriptTxt, elem) as IWebElement;
    }
```