# Capybara ,MSEdgeDriver : Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: javascript error: arguments[0].matches is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara, microsoft-edge

I am executing test case using ruby 2.7, Selenium -WebDriver 3.142.7, Capybara 3.35.3 ,MSEdgeDriver 91.0.864.48,Cucumber 5.3.0. . My page is being killed just after loading. Please find below logs.

Starting MSEdgeDriver 91.0.864.48 (27d934e7c76a9077a5bb7cc1512b894d360169ec) on port 17557
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
2021-07-08 16:24:50 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 17557]
2021-07-08 16:24:51 INFO Selenium -> POST session
2021-07-08 16:24:51 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:17557/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","version":"","platform":"WINDOWS","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"nativeEvents":true,"rotatable":true,"ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--disable-web-security"],"w3c":false}},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--disable-web-security"],"w3c":false}}]}}

2021-07-08 16:25:02 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "User-Agent"=>"selenium/3.142.7 (ruby macosx)", "Content-Length"=>"2153"}
2021-07-08 16:25:02 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"4f68a951ade6a304143ceb876d58f8dd","status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"0.1779752229405389-1"}]}
2021-07-08 16:25:02 INFO Selenium -> POST session/4f68a951ade6a304143ceb876d58f8dd/execute
2021-07-08 16:25:02 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:17557/session/4f68a951ade6a304143ceb876d58f8dd/execute | {"script":"return arguments[0].matches(':disabled, select:disabled *')","args":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"0.1779752229405389-1"}]}
2021-07-08 16:25:02 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "User-Agent"=>"selenium/3.142.7 (ruby macosx)", "Content-Length"=>"144"}
2021-07-08 16:25:02 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"4f68a951ade6a304143ceb876d58f8dd","status":17,"value":{"message":"javascript error: arguments[0].matches is not a function\n  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=91.0.864.64)\n  (Driver info: msedgedriver=91.0.864.48 (27d934e7c76a9077a5bb7cc1512b894d360169ec),platform=Mac OS X 11.4.0 x86_64)"}}

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to execute script code via WebDirver? If you are using [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), then it should work, as the answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395098/how-to-determine-if-an-element-is-matched-by-css-selector). But I'm not sure if there is any problem in your code, if you can provide a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem, this will help to find out the cause of the problem.

Comment: @XudongPeng Hi Sir, I did lot of research and i feel the actual issue is with css selector.I changed #element :username, '.login-box form:first-of-type #username' to element :username,'#username[type=text]' ,then it started working but issue is i am using native event to interact with element example : userField = self.login_page.username
userField.native.send_keys(username) And when Capybara does not find any element then it kills the page

Comment: @XudongPeng Hi Sir, I got the issue . If we use R spec with assertion to "be_visible" then it works with chrome and it doesn't work with Edge Browser. I replaced it with "be_present" and it is working for both browser.

Comment: @Prophet I am sorry for inconvenience , i will take care of it

Comment: Hi @Theautomator  You can put the solution into an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sure sir @XudongPeng

Answer (score 1):

I did lot of research and i feel the actual issue is with css selector.I changed #element :username, '.login-box form:first-of-type #username' to element :username,'#username[type=text]' ,then it started printing correct error. I was using "be_visible" Rspec, because of this I was getting error "MSEdgeDriver : Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: javascript error: arguments[0].matches is not a function".I replaced it with "be_present" and it is working for Edge and Chrome browser.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.